# Is there any "diff" mechanism to calculate the rows differences?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an enormous table with blocks of data with **huge similarities** and **slight differences**.
I was wondering if, similarly to a `diff` command, I could compute the `deltas` (the differences) of those blocks (respect to the previous one or to the first one, let's say) and **elegantly store only the added/missing rows**. For example:

```
+-------+-------+------+
| Block | Order | Data |
+-------+-------+------+
|     1 |     1 |    A |
|     1 |     2 |    B |
|     1 |     3 |    C |
|     1 |     4 |    D |
+-------+-------+------+
|     2 |     1 |    A |
|     2 |     2 |    B |
|     2 |     3 |    D | <- missing 'C'
+-------+-------+------+
|     3 |     1 |    A |
|     3 |     2 |    B |
|     3 |     3 |    C |
|     3 |     4 |    D |
|     3 |     5 |    E | <- extra 'E'
+-------+-------+------+
```

That way, I would only need to store something like `--order=4` (missing `C`) for block `2`, and `++after=4 order=5 'E'` for block `3`. A `diff` mechanism would save hundreds of MB of repetitions. Is this possible somehow?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How can you store a missing row if it _isn't_ present in your table?

Comment: Are you comparing block 2 to block 1, and block 3 to block 1? Are you always comparing to block 1 or just to the previous block? If the previous block, then block 3 would have `extra 'E'` and `extra 'C'`?

Comment: Does `block=1` is considered as "base block", and all differences must be got against it? or you need the comparing result for each blocks pair (maybe assuming additionally that the block with the least number is considered as "base")?

Comment: The output like "missing C" and "extra E" can be obtained easily. To receive the output like "--order=4" is more difficult... and it is unclear what output you need if, for example, block 2 contain only A and D (theoretically there can be 2 different outputs depends on removing order).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen A `diff` output can indicate that something is missing, it may be possible as well in SQL @Akina I could use `block=1` as the base block, or just use the previous one, that is inconsequential. The output will always differ depending on the base block. The important matter is to have a recoverable way to compute the original sequence from the differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to adapt this to your situation:
First, replicating your example (with an extra block, to help confirm my testing)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blocks` (
  `block` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `seq` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`block`,`seq`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `blocks` (`block`, `seq`, `content`) VALUES
  (1, 1, 'A'),
  (1, 2, 'B'),
  (1, 3, 'C'),
  (1, 4, 'D'),
  (2, 1, 'A'),
  (2, 2, 'B'),
  (2, 3, 'D'),
  (3, 1, 'A'),
  (3, 2, 'B'),
  (3, 3, 'C'),
  (3, 4, 'D'),
  (3, 5, 'E'),
  (4, 1, 'A'),
  (4, 2, 'B'),
  (4, 3, 'D')  
 ;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `masterblock` (
  `seq` int(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `content` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`seq`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `masterblock` (`seq`, `content`) VALUES
  (1, 'A'),
  (2, 'B'),
  (3, 'C'),
  (4, 'D');
```

Then this query (if your DB supports FULL JOIN syntax, this could no doubt be written in simpler form):

```
SELECT b.block, b.seq, b.content, m.content AS mastercontent
FROM blocks b
LEFT JOIN masterblock m
ON b.seq = m.seq
WHERE m.content IS NULL
OR b.content <> m.content
UNION ALL
SELECT distinct b.block, m.seq, NULL, m.content FROM
masterblock m
INNER JOIN
blocks b
ON m.seq NOT IN (SELECT seq FROM blocks WHERE block = b.block) 
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

Produces this result (as tested on SQLFiddle)

[image: SQL Output]